# Perl split function before regex, not after

Tags: function, perl, split

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings ;
use strict ;

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $str = " 30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Elvis Presly: BJ: Bloomberg Runs30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Elvis Presly: DS: ICE DATA = INC101848366130th Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Putin: Cortese's ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs issue30th Mar 2020 6:43:28 pm Elvis Presly: yeap31st Mar 2020 4:11:22 am Indie Rock: VK : RE: XS2018777099 & XS2018777172 - INC1018491954 31st Mar 2020 6:31:17 am Dash Riprock: NW: RE: SABSM 6.125 YTW - INC101849584331st Mar 2020 6:52:06 am Dash Riprock: KB: RE: Cpty issue for Trader on CDS STATS bookings - SDS 42625375 - PENDING ROKOS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT (JERSEY) LP - INC101849631331st Mar 2020 7:26:40 am Dash Riprock: AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC101849710231st Mar 2020 7:45:36 am Dash Riprock: JK: RE: Chris White books - INC101849738031st Mar 2020 8:11:10 am Charlie Brown: KB: RE: BOOKBUILDER Allocs Delays - urgent - INC101849791631st Mar 2020 8:21:15 am Charlie Brown: VK: RE: Can you get me set up to view TRAX History?  - INC101849813331st Mar 2020 8:30:36 am Charlie Brown: WJ: RE: Bulking Booking P&L - INC101849829231st Mar 2020
";



#my @words = split / /, $str ;
my @words = split /(\d+th|st|rd)/, $str ;


print Dumper \@words;
```

Split does what is should

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' ',
          '30th',
          ' Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Elvis Presly: BJ: Bloomberg Runs',
          '30th',
          ' Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Elvis Presly: DS: ICE DATA = INC',
          '101848366130th', (this did not split  - it happens) 
          ' Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Putin: Cortese\'s ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs 
issue',
          '30th',
          ' Mar 2020 6:43:
```

However what I really need is the line ending to come before the date, so the data is listed as

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' ',
          '30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Elvis Presly: BJ: Bloomberg Runs',
          '30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Elvis Presly: DS: ICE DATA = INC',
          '101848366130th',
          ' Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Putin: Cortese\'s ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs 
issue',
          '30th Mar 2020 6:43:
```

Answer (score 4):

When using split, you need to specify what's *in between* the bits you want to keep. In this case, the separator is the 0-length string that's followed by a date. For that, you can use the following:

```
split /(?=\d+(?:th|st|nd|rd))/, $str
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need `nd` for "second".

```
split /(?=\d{2}(?:st|nd|rd|th) \w{3} \d{4})/a, $str;
```

The `/a` forces the ASCII interpretation of `\d`, so things like "६" don't match.

The zero look-ahead assertion `(?=)` is used to split the string right before the match, i.e. at the date start (thanks [ikegami](/users/589924/ikegami) for the idea).

You could also use

```
split /(\d{2}(?:st|nd|rd|th) \w{3} \d{4}(?: \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [ap]m)?) ?/a
```

to separate the timestamps:

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' ',
          '30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm',
          'Basant Jain: BJ: Bloomberg Runs',
          '30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm',
          'Basant Jain: DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661',
          # ...
          '31st Mar 2020 8:30:36 am',
          'Kishan Bholah: WJ: RE: Bulking Booking P&L - INC1018498292',
          '31st Mar 2020'
        ];
```

Note that `\d+st|nd` doesn't do what you need: the `\d+` is part only of the first alternative, you need to use parentheses to group things together. I used the non-matching variant `(?:...)` to prevent [split](http://p3rl.org/split) from including the match in the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear why `split` is used by OP.

As alternative *substitute* can be utilized to inject *new line* before dates.

`split` was added to place lines into an array *lines* to achieve desired result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = " 30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Elvis Presly: BJ: Bloomberg Runs30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Elvis Presly: DS: ICE DATA = INC101848366130th Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Putin: Cortese's ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs issue30th Mar 2020 6:43:28 pm Elvis Presly: yeap31st Mar 2020 4:11:22 am Indie Rock: VK : RE: XS2018777099 & XS2018777172 - INC1018491954 31st Mar 2020 6:31:17 am Dash Riprock: NW: RE: SABSM 6.125 YTW - INC101849584331st Mar 2020 6:52:06 am Dash Riprock: KB: RE: Cpty issue for Trader on CDS STATS bookings - SDS 42625375 - PENDING ROKOS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT (JERSEY) LP - INC101849631331st Mar 2020 7:26:40 am Dash Riprock: AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC101849710231st Mar 2020 7:45:36 am Dash Riprock: JK: RE: Chris White books - INC101849738031st Mar 2020 8:11:10 am Charlie Brown: KB: RE: BOOKBUILDER Allocs Delays - urgent - INC101849791631st Mar 2020 8:21:15 am Charlie Brown: VK: RE: Can you get me set up to view TRAX History?  - INC101849813331st Mar 2020 8:30:36 am Charlie Brown: WJ: RE: Bulking Booking P&L - INC101849829231st Mar 2020
";

$str =~ s/(\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd) \w{3} \d{4})/\n$1/g;

say $str;

my @lines = split "\n", $str;

say Dumper(\@lines);
```

Comment: I reverted to original version -- which is not _fully complaint_ as if for some reason in data input will be `13nd` or `16st` then it will be accepted.

Comment: Don'tuse captures for nothing, it slows things down for nothing. `(th|st|nd|rd)` => `(?:th|st|nd|rd)`

Comment: Speaking of avoiding captures, captures are entirely unnecessary here: `s/(?=\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd) \w{3} \d{4})/\n/g` Not sure if that's faster

Comment: @ikegami -- it should be a huge file to even detect _slowness_ in processing. But as **tip** it is a good advise.

Comment: to me, it's more significant for code readability; if I read code that captures I should be able to expect to see some use of the captured values

Comment: @ysth, I couldn't agree more